# How to combine Date from one column and Time from another?

Tags: r

I imported some data from Excel that has separate columns for "Date" and "Time".  When I imported the "Time" column, it returned with `1899-12-31 19:00:00` with the date `1899-12-31` for every single time value.

I would like to create a new column that would combine the date from the "Date" column and time from the "Time" column so I can do some calculations.

```
# A tibble: 207 x 2
   DoS                 ToS                
   <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2018-01-27 00:00:00 1899-12-31 19:00:00
 2 2018-02-07 00:00:00 1899-12-31 15:45:00
 3 2018-02-13 00:00:00 1899-12-31 23:00:00
 4 2018-02-15 00:00:00 1899-12-31 13:45:00
 5 2018-02-16 00:00:00 1899-12-31 10:00:00
 6 2018-02-19 00:00:00 1899-12-31 15:00:00
 7 2018-02-20 00:00:00 1899-12-31 15:05:00
 8 2018-02-21 00:00:00 1899-12-31 15:00:00

> dput(head(sample, 10))
structure(list(DoS = structure(c(1517011200, 1517961600, 1518480000, 
1518652800, 1518739200, 1518998400, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 
1519862400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ToS = structure(c(-2209006800, -2209018500, -2208992400, 
    -2209025700, -2209039200, -2209021200, -2209020900, -2209021200, 
    -2209033800, -2209005000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Is there some way I can extract the time values and paste it to the Date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, we can extract date from `DoS` and time from `ToS` and combine them together.

```
transform(sample, Datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(DoS), format(ToS, "%T"))))

#          DoS                 ToS            Datetime
#1  2018-01-27 1899-12-31 19:00:00 2018-01-27 19:00:00
#2  2018-02-07 1899-12-31 15:45:00 2018-02-07 15:45:00
#3  2018-02-13 1899-12-31 23:00:00 2018-02-13 23:00:00
#4  2018-02-15 1899-12-31 13:45:00 2018-02-15 13:45:00
#5  2018-02-16 1899-12-31 10:00:00 2018-02-16 10:00:00
#6  2018-02-19 1899-12-31 15:00:00 2018-02-19 15:00:00
#7  2018-02-20 1899-12-31 15:05:00 2018-02-20 15:05:00
#8  2018-02-21 1899-12-31 15:00:00 2018-02-21 15:00:00
#9  2018-02-22 1899-12-31 11:30:00 2018-02-22 11:30:00
#10 2018-03-01 1899-12-31 19:30:00 2018-03-01 19:30:00
```